# how to modify a dart/flutter package?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use  a dart package. Currently its under dependencies in `pubspec.yaml`. And it works fine.  However I need to make a few minor changes to the package. Do I need to import the whole package into my project and make changes there or is there an easier way?

Comment: just clone the package into your project and edit it however you like. and import the package like this in your pubspec.yaml >>                                package_name:
    path: /path

Answer (score 0):

You *should* clone the package from it's own repository and then just import it using the path instead. For example, if you have let's say, a package called `foo: ^1.0.0` and want to modify it:

1. Go to it's GitHub project and clone it to somewhere in your machine;
2. Change the path in your `pubspec.yaml` to:

```
foo:
 path: [your package path]
```

Have in mind that if you have the project stored in VC, the reference won't work and thus you should always point to a remote dependency unless it's shipped with your app as well (eg. `path: ../dependency`).